# How to translate second argument for Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...")

Tags: android, multilingual

I was wondering how to set the second argument createChooser to be parse from strings.xml? So my app is more multilingual.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

i tried

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "@string/btnsendemailtext"));
```

regards,

Comment: `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.btnsendemailtext));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
String title = getResources().getString(R.string.btnsendemailtext);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, title));
```

Comment: added up using your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.btnsendemailtext)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.btnsendemailtext));
```